# Story about a group of students who convince their teacher he's from Mars!

Tags: story-identification

There was a movie I missed but the premise was that the students of a school or college convince their teacher he's an alien from Mars!

I always thought the premise was funny and I'd like to be able to watch it but I don't know the title.

Answer (score 3):

The only movie I can think of with that premise is [Simon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081518/)

Some of the details match, and some don't; IMDB's synopsis describes the movie as follows:

> A group of scientist take Simon, a psychology professor, as a test person for a brainwash experiment. After that they try to convince him that he was a living-being from another planet.